# JQuery , On Enter key code 13 (a button is triggered ), this works only the first time but not afterwards

Tags: jquery, jsf-2

I have a modal which has a text box and a commandButton. 
Once I enter the value into the text and press Enter 
    commandButton is triggerd. 
This functionality works the first time i.e.

1. when i enter text and press enter, button is triggered and modal stays
2. Now when i enter the text and press enter second time.. the button is not triggered but modal closes.

Below is the code for Input Text and button

```
  <input type="text" id="textid" />
  <h:commandButton class="button" id="commandButtonID" 
                  onclick="console.log('buttnClicked')"/>
```

Below is the keypress event

```
 $("#textid").keypress(function(event){
            if(event.which == 13){
                 $("#formName\\:commandButtonID").trigger("click");
             return false;        
            }  
        });
```

If there is an answer out there, please guide me through the answer. I did my search in stackoverflow and did not find.

Comment: Could you please paste more code here???

Comment: What more code you require?

Comment: Whatever your code is absolutely right but seems like other components or script might interrupting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it working as expected, changing the selector to trigger the event:

```
$("#commandButtonID").trigger("click");
```

At least in this jsfiddle, this work very well, check:

https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/e087n7vh/3/

Comment: Button is triggered with the call that you have mentioned.. but it should trigger with keypress "Enter" . In the code I have written, button is triggered for 1st instance but not the second time. In my code, when i press enter second time.. my modal is closing.

Comment: Please check the fiddle that I have provided. In that, the event is triggered all the time. With the code that you put in your question, this work.